# Assigning values to an Array for use in a while loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am wishing to export data from an Excel sheet to multiple CSV files using an Array, I have written the code that creates the export without issue, but I cannot seem to get my head around assigning the initial values to an Array and then using some kind of while loop from the data in the Array to produce the desired exports.

The unique values I wish to hold in the Array are located in Column A of sheet 1, obviously the values in the column are not unique, but I only wish to reference (add to the Array) once.

Once I have the values in the Array I want to place the code in a while loop to export the data based on the unique value in the Array.

Below in a snippet of my current code, which in isolation works fine;

```
Public InvDate

Sub ExportAccLinesLoop()
    Dim fso, FilePathName, FilePath, Station, StationName, StationDate, Exp, d1, WC, dd, mm, yy
    dd = Left(InvDate, 2)
    mm = Mid(InvDate, 4, 2)
    yy = Right(InvDate, 2)
    FilePath = "\\Sunbury-xxx\xxx\Parcels\Attachments\"
    FilePathName = FilePath & "Tmp.csv"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set rRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FilePath) Then fso.CreateFolder (FilePath)  'create folder if it does not exist
    Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePathName, 8, True)
    inputFile.WriteLine (Chr(34) & "Rate Acc" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Movement" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Ledger Acc" & Chr(34))  ‘Write Header values
    inputFile.Close

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Value = "WAR" Then
            RateAcc = rCell(1, 1)
            DelCol = rCell(1, 2)
            LedgerAcc = rCell(1, 3)            

            If Not fso.FolderExists(FilePath) Then fso.CreateFolder (FilePath)  'create folder if it does not exist
            Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePathName, 8, True)
            inputFile.WriteLine (Chr(34) & RateAcc & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & DelCol & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & LedgerAcc & Chr(34))  ‘Write Line values

            inputFile.Close
        End If 'rCell
    Next rCell
    fso.CopyFile FilePathName, FilePath & yy & mm & dd & "-" & LedgerAcc & "-" & RateAcc & "-" & "TRAN.csv" 'Copy Tmp.csv to correct filename
    fso.DeleteFile FilePathName 'Delete Tmp.csv

End Sub
```

I assume the while loop will start after `Set rRange`, indeed the unique Array values will come from the same range, but I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `Dictionary` object which can give you unique items from sourcelist. You can loop through it then.

Comment: Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim objDict As Object
Dim key As Variant

Set objDict = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For Each key In .Value
            If Not objDict.Contains(key) Then objDict.Add key
        Next
    End With
End With
```